# MacBook Pro Fan broken again

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I replaced my MacBook Pro (mid-2015)'s left fan as I noticed it had stopped working (had to investigate what was causing the kernal_task to use all CPU and completely slow laptop down). The right fan still worked (and continues to work) just fine.

3 months later, a couple of days ago, and the left fan has stopped working again.

Has anyone got any thoughts about this? Happy to give more details of my usage and I know I could replace the fan again, but it's a bit annoying and would love to get to the bottom of what is causing this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on what brand the fan is. Don't get me wrong any hardware can fail, it happened with one of the original fans. But the second failed fan could just be from a manufacturer that makes sub-standard fans. There is not much you can do in software to a Mac that would make a fan fail other than making it run *all the time.* Honesly I would find a different brand of fan from a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks Steve. It was listed as a genuine replacement, but I'm not savvy enough to tell the difference. If I do opt to replace, do you have any recommendations for manufacturers or online shops (I'm UK based)?